# Библиотека Math.h в c

Tags: c, математика

Ошибка совсем другая:

Парни! У меня совершенно иная ошибка, я проверял руками, только выделяя память по 16 байт. Попробовав выделить 256кб при попытке записать нижележащим кодом, получил segmentation fault. В чем беда, все равно не знаю.

```
====
```

Первый текст:

Решил попробовать себя в простых задачках. Вот она http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001
Накидал быстренько такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
  // int mem = 256*1024; // input raw <256KB
  int mem = 16; // for tests
  double *arr;
  arr = (double *)malloc(mem);

  printf("%.4fl\n", sqrt((double)424));
  int i = mem/sizeof(int);
  while(i>0 && scanf("%lf", &arr[--i]))
      ;

  printf("\n---------------------------------------\n\n");

  for(; i<mem/sizeof(int) ;i++){
      printf("%.4f\n", sqrt(arr[i]));
  }

return 0;
}
```

По условиям необходимо компилировать со следующими директивами:

```
gcc -static -fno-strict-aliasing -DONLINE_JUDGE -lm -s 
    -Wl,--stack=67108864 -O2 -o %1.exe %1.
```

Но в таком случае компилятор кидает ошибку:

> undefined reference to `sqrt'

Хотя -lm есть. Если сунуть в код просто printf("%lf", sqrt((double)1552423)) - то никаких ошибок нет и корень выдается.

Я как гордый предок макак скрутил директивы несколько иначе: gcc -static -fno-strict-aliasing -s -O2 -o execute src.c -lm - у меня на машине работает, а система тестирования кидает Runtime error (access violation).

Что делать?

п.с: какой способ был бы правильным для считывания неизвестного количества входных данных? Не городить же структуры руками.

Comment: Странно. У меня i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 компилирует-собирает (не сам, конечно, ld) без проблем. С Вашими ключами.

Comment: У меня gcc(не mingw) 4.7.2.
С моими которые по условию или что я накрутил?
Попробуйте раскомментить int mem = 256*1024, собрать и ввести в консоль число, если не сложно. У меня segmentation fault кидало.

Comment: @iksuy, вот я дурной.  
Но все же мне интересно узнать, что стало причиной ошибки.

Comment: чёрт, извиняюсь, случайно запостил в комментарий, перенес в ответ.
причиной ошибка вероятнее всего стало то, что поток данных, который вам отдается не всегда равен 256кб. Соответственно если он равен, допустим 100кб, то вы дальше пытаетесь читать, а там уже не ваша область памяти, таким образом получается сегфолт.

Comment: Если конкретнее, то 

    while(i>0 && scanf("%lf", &arr[--i]));

вот эта строчка. выход из этого цикла будет, когда одно из условий false.
Если данных будет меньше, то i будет больше 0, а scanf считает константу EOF, а она равна -1, а -1 в Cи это true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там же у них в guide сказано вот что:

> You should know how to read the input data until the end of stream to solve certain problems. The following examples show how to implement reading input until the end of stream in case input data consists of numbers, lines or separate characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
// numbers
int n;
while (scanf("%d", &n) != EOF)
{
   ...
}
// lines
char line[1000];
while (gets(line))
{
   ...
}
// characters
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
   ...
}
```

В данном случае вам гарантировано будут поступать на вход числа типа long, и функция scanf будет их кушать. Она пропускает whitespaces при чтении числовых типов.